# How to use right_click_menu with multiple InputText elements?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

How do you distinguish between multiple elements on the same window when using right_click_menu in PySimpleGUI? For example, with the code below, how do I tell which one of the two InputText elements I am trying to use the right_click_menu with? If I copy something to the clipboard and then right-click 'Paste' on one of the Input fields, the same data will appear in both fields. When I right-click on one of the InputText fields, how can I write the code to identify which one I'm on?:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

INPUT1 = 'INPUT1'
INPUT2 = 'INPUT2'

right_click_menu = ['',['Paste']]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Input1'), sg.InputText('', key='INPUT1', right_click_menu = right_click_menu)],
    [sg.Text('Input2'), sg.InputText('', key='INPUT2', right_click_menu = right_click_menu)],
    [sg.Button(' OK '), sg.Button(' Exit ')]
    ]

window = sg.Window('Multiple Elements', layout)

input1:sg.InputText = window[INPUT1]
input2:sg.InputText = window[INPUT2]

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (' Exit ', None):
        break

    if event == 'Paste':
        # How to tell whether I am right-clicking on INPUT1 or INPUT2?
        # With just one Input element, I could just do this: 

        input1.Widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, window.TKroot.clipboard_get())

        # What do I do when there is a second InputText field? 
        # Below won't work because I'll get the same text pasted into both fields.

        input2.Widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, window.TKroot.clipboard_get())



    if event == ' OK ':
        pass
        #Do blah

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#keys-for-menus

> A key is indicated by adding `::` after a menu entry, followed by the key.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

INPUT1 = 'INPUT1'
INPUT2 = 'INPUT2'

right_click_menu = [['',[f'Paste::Paste {i}']] for i in range(2)]

layout = [
    [sg.Text('Input1'), sg.InputText('', key='INPUT1', right_click_menu = right_click_menu[0])],
    [sg.Text('Input2'), sg.InputText('', key='INPUT2', right_click_menu = right_click_menu[1])],
    [sg.Button(' OK '), sg.Button(' Exit ')]
    ]

window = sg.Window('Multiple Elements', layout)

input1:sg.InputText = window[INPUT1]
input2:sg.InputText = window[INPUT2]

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (' Exit ', None):
        break

    if event.startswith('Paste'):
        element = input1 if event.split()[1] == '0' else input2
        element.Widget.insert(sg.tk.INSERT, window.TKroot.clipboard_get())

window.close()
```